# Strongly named assembly in place of a non-named assembly

Tags: .net, strongname, portable-class-library

Is there a way to use a strongly named assembly in place of a non-named assembly?

The real question is this:

I am creating a library (eg: SqliteOrm.dll) (Portable Class Library in my instance, by the problem is with any type) that references another library (eg: System.Data.dll) which differs depending on the platform (iOS, Android, WP, desktop and WinRT). This library (SqliteOrm.dll) is then consumed by applications from each platform, but will switch System.Data.dll.

However, System.Data.dll exists in the GAC with a strong name. This causes an exception when the library is consumed:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The reason I am doing this is because System.Data.dll does not exist in WP but does in M4A. I use the native System.Data.dll on M4A, but my own version on WP. My version only includes the neccessary types, so it does differ in this way.

I am currently testing using Metro and Desktop apps, and this is where the exception is occuring. I vaguely recall something about the fact that the M4A runtime doesn't actually do the check, but I would like my library to work on the desktop as well.

Does anyone have any tips for me, or is this whole thing a bad practice?

Comment: Where did the System.Data without strong name come from? Also: what platforms have a problem here? If it is just desktop, is handling AppDomain.AssemblyResolve an option? *Personally* (based on my own experience with multi-platform libraries), I suspect you'd find it easier to have a per-platform build, and just reference the appropriate dll. With a NuGet deployment this is pretty easy to automate, too.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using your own System.Data everywhere. Probably a lot less painful than anything else.

There is something here that suggests an alternative: http://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2007/08/30/strong-naming-remoting-nothg-but-ye-liveliest-awfulness/

And then there's the crazy way: it actually works to set your assembly to be delay-signed by the MS-key, then register the assembly as a delay-signed assembly at install time (on WP). Of course, now you need admin rights to install and can confuse the heck out of anybody expecting a more sane System.Data on WP.